# Copy a file with a certain string in the filename in python

Tags: python, file, copy, wildcard, shutil

I need to copy a file that contains some string, call it `mystring`, in the filename from a directory to another. At the moment I use

```
for file in glob.glob(FileNameM):
        shutil.copy(file, dest);
```

where `dest` is the destination directory and

```
FileNameM = source_directory + some_known_string + mystring + "*"
```

This code works fine when there is an extension only after `mystring`, but if there is something else plus an extension the code fails.

Example `FileNameM` that works:

```
/home/eugene/GDrive/Project-related/Skyrmion_Lattice_Output/Output_Good_Enough/Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.11_a_3.63311050137*
```

and leads to the file

```
/home/eugene/GDrive/Project-related/Skyrmion_Lattice_Output/Output_Good_Enough/Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.11_a_3.63311050137.dat
```

Example `FileNameM` that doesn't work:

```
/home/eugene/GDrive/Project-related/Skyrmion_Lattice_Output/Output/Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.12_a_3.6341634222*
```

and this shall lead to the file

```
/home/eugene/GDrive/Project-related/Skyrmion_Lattice_Output/Output/Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.12_a_3.63416342223.dat
```

Do you have any idea how can I improve?

Comment: Could you show an example of a path that works and of a path that does not to help to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Added examples to the main body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it with your example filenames and got both filenames by `glob.glob()`, even with more characters missing:

```
import glob
    FileNameM = 'test\Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.12_a_3.6341634*'
    for file in glob.glob(FileNameM):
        print(file)
# test\Parameters__triangular_N_225_kappa_1.0_beta_0.12_a_3.63416342223.dat
```

Running on Windows; a dummy file was in the subfolder `test` next to the script.